# Different values for peripheral name on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm pairing an iOS app to a BT peripheral and filtering out incorrect peripherals. My peripheral has a BLE GAP device name as well as a local name (CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) in the advertisement data.

The below code doesn't specify which to display, but returns different name values on iPhone 4s and iPhone 6. In both cases the iOS devices are running 8.1.2.

Per Apple docs, CB should default to the GAP name if both names are present. Any hints on why iPhone 6 default to the local name instead?

---

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"didDiscoverPeripheral = %@",peripheral.name);

    if ([peripheral.name isEqual:MY_DEVICE_NAME]) {
        [self.centralManager stopScan];
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the BLE peripheral an iOS device?

Comment: No. It's custom hardware.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok, I was asking because I have seen strange behaviour where you are working between two devices with the same iCloud account - it seems they are implicitly paired and paired iOS devices expose more information than unpaired devices.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's really interesting information, is this implicit pairing described anywhere in the docs?

Comment: No, not that I have found.  The Core Bluetooth programming guide is pretty light on detail anyway.  I created a proof of concept app to answer another question on SO regarding pairing and the delegate callbacks you get when pairing completes/fails/is cancelled but I couldn't get the pairing dialog to even show.  Finally I installed my app on my daughter's iPad (it has a different iCloud account) and the pairing dialog came up straight away as it should.  There was no pairing shown between my iPad and my iPhone in settings but the pairing dialog never presented and I could read encrypted data

Comment: My theory is purely based on observation and guess work but it kind of makes sense when you consider the interaction between devices with iOS8 - sharing phone call & text messages for example - there must be a secure relationship